# Specifying a profile for awscrt.auth.AwsCredentialsProvider

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-credentials

I'm creating an `AwsCredentialsProvider` class ([api docs](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-crt-python/api/mqtt.html)) from:

```
awscrt.auth.AwsCredentialsProvider.new_default_chain(client_bootstrap)
```

I get an error `AWS_ERROR_MQTT_UNEXPECTED_HANGUP` which I believe occurs because my AWS credentials are under a non default profile in `~/.aws/credentials` (based on [this git issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/issues/115)).

But I can't see any way to create an `AwsCredentialsProvider` with a specified profile.

Comment: Is there possible for you to value of `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` and `AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE` environment variable to location of your aws credentials file ? and check

Comment: It locates the credentials file just fine, but how can I specify which profile in the credentials file to use? Is there an environment variable to specify profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom credentials file path set environment variables `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` and `AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE`

For default profile set environment variable `AWS_PROFILE` with AWS profile name you would like to select as default. In order to use at runtime, this AWS profile name must be present in your AWS credentials file with valid configurations.

If you use only one AWS region, then you can also set environment variable `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`. At times it saves few lines of code, where you might need to specify a AWS region.